# Are these the basis vectors?

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, linear-algebra

A [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) of a vector space \$V\$ is a set of vectors \$B\$ such that every vector \$\vec v \in V\$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination of the vectors in \$B\$. In other words, let \$B = \{\vec b_1, \dots, \vec b_n\}\$ be a  basis of some vector space \$V\$. For every possible \$\vec v \in V\$, we can say that

$$\vec v = \lambda_1 \vec b_1 + \lambda_2 \vec b_2 + \cdots + \lambda_n \vec b_n$$

for some **unique** real numbers \$\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n\$. Note that this requires the vectors in \$B\$ to be [linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) (i.e., you cannot write a vector in \$B\$ as a linear combination of other vectors in \$B\$).

For example, let \$V = \mathbb R^2\$ i.e. the set of all 2 dimensional vectors. We can see that \$B = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}\$ is a basis of \$V\$, as any 2 dimensional vector \$\vec v = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}\$ can be written as

$$\vec v = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}x + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}y$$

Furthermore, examine \$B = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \right\}\$. As the two vectors are linearly independent, they must form a basis of \$\mathbb R^2\$, and so we can write any 2-dimensional vector as a combination of the two. For example,

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -10 \end{pmatrix} = -2\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + -4\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

However, note that if we have \$B = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \right\}\$, then this does not form a basis for all 3 dimensional vectors. There exists no such \$\lambda_1, \lambda_2\$ such that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 6 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\lambda_1 + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\lambda_2$$

and so \$B\$ is not a basis for \$\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 6 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix}\$.

---

You are to take a vector \$\vec v \in \mathbb Z^m\$ of \$m\$ integers, and a list of \$n\$ vectors \$B = \{\vec b_1, \dots, \vec b_n\}\$. You should then output two distinct consistent values to indicate whether or not \$B\$ forms a basis for \$\vec v\$ (more precisely, whether \$B\$ forms a basis for some space containing \$\vec v\$). That is, whether or not there exists a unique set of numbers \$\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n\$ such that

$$\vec v = \lambda_1 \vec b_1 + \lambda_2 \vec b_2 + \cdots + \lambda_n \vec b_n$$

You may assume that \$\vec b_i \in \mathbb Z^m\$ for all vectors \$b_i \in B\$ - that is, they all have the same number of elements as \$\vec v\$, and they are all integer vectors.

You may take the inputs in any [reasonable, convenient format and method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/66833), including a list of lists of \$B\$, or a list of numbers for \$\vec v\$ etc. The output may be any two distinct, consistent values to indicate whether or not \$B\$ is a basis. You may freely choose these values.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

```
B
v
Output (λ1, λ2, ..., λn or reason)

[[8, 1, 2], [-7, -8, -9], [-1, 9, -5]]
[12, 36, -4]
True (1, -1, 3)

[[-9, -3]]
[3, 1]
True (-1/3)

[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
[1, -1, -1]
True (1, -1)

[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
[4, 6, 10]
False (shown above)

[[7, -2], [-10, -6], [-4, 9]]
[1, -21]
False (too many unknowns, an infinite number of solutions exist)

[[-1, 8, 1, 6, 3], [8, -6, -5, -10, 6], [-8, -3, -3, -4, 5], [-6, -6, 0, 3, 9], [2, 2, 0, -1, -3]]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
False ([-6, -6, 0, 3, 9] and [2, 2, 0, -1, -3] are linearly dependent, so any way of writing the sum is not unique)
```

Comment: Note that "whether or not \$B\$ forms a basis for \$\vec v\$" isn't mathematially correct; vector spaces have bases but individual vectors do not (and replacing \$\vec v\$ by \$\langle\vec v\rangle\$ doesn't make it correct either). By the criteria described, we're being asked whether \$B\$ is linearly independent and simultaneously \$\vec v \in{}\$Span\$B\$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yeah, I'm not too happy with the wording, but I believe that, although it isn't technically correct, it makes enough sense in the context of the challenge. If you have a better way of expressing the concept that \$\vec v\$ can be expressed as some linear combination of a subset of \$B\$, feel free to edit.

Comment: made a stab at it. I agree that the challenge itself is described well enough

Answer (score 14):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>43</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```matlab
@(B,v)(r=rank(B))-rows(B)|r-rank([B;v])
```

Anonymous function that inputs the set of vectors as a matrix **B** with each vector in a row, and **v** as a row vector. The output is `true` (displayed as `1`) if `B` is not a basis for `v`, and `false` (displayed as `0`) if it is.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBBCoMwELz3FXs0sCuaaFoJQvEb4kFKvRQq2GIv/budTSy9FWKYncyMk8yX57het4layvN8O2cdryZb2mW837LOGFnm1wPgvUik@i6sg9mmrD8xlUw2kByZBJM0wKAawHpg6ktLzpNUgzlAL8o75R2ciYO6wBDijrDo4pgifyQVk8dUDIZUckw1SijEA@C4@SbZPUYjU2M4XVAsXotyMqpPObd/yKhDkvjYACTuZ1lXsVd0@19@C0/zAQ)

#### How it works

The set of vectors defined by the rows of **B** is a basis for **v** if and only if the rank of the matrix **B** equals its number of rows (i.e. the rows of **B** are linearly independent) *and* the rank of the extended matrix with `v` as last row is the same (i.e. **v** is in the linear span of the rows of **B**).

To save bytes, the code checks if *either* of those conditions is *not* satisfied; that is, if the rank of **B** minus its number of rows is nonzero *or* if the rank of **B** minus that of the extended matrix is nonzero.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 218 bytes

Expects `(matrix)(vector)`. Returns \$0\$ or \$1\$.

```javascript
m=>v=>!(g=m=>m.reduce(o=>m.some((r,y)=>r.some((_,x)=>m[y+w]&&(D=m=>+m||m.reduce((s,[v],i)=>v*D(m.map(([,...r])=>r).filter(_=>i--))-s,0))(m.slice(y,y-~w).map(r=>r.slice(x,x-~w)))/r[x+w]))*++w||o,w=0)-w)(m)&!~g([...m,v])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVDNbsIwDL7vKboLiqmTtQ2wcUhPvEVUIQQFdWooSll/pIpX75yUMWniMqmR7K/fj@3PXbOr97a4XPm5OuTjUY1GpY1KX9lJUWWEzQ9f@5xVrq4rkzNmsQeV2nu3xY46o/uwzWYztnGq0AzDQ8lq1E2GBbGa@YYZYXYXxjQKIWzmjEAci/KaW7ZVacE5AK8xAiBmXRZk0GPPby14nfXBHu6wczDAm9UdhQPMw7AdhgpbFQFvyQBmr7cT05RksMlg3FfnuipzUVYndmRaf2AQY5BkGGj@jgGnnq99R/CammWWAdNxgoFcUbugkJe/JtwRpSdK8ntGIbfI/SLn6B7pfUno3z80Cwxokjh6JnErTMvEJOErX5Jg/UhLnka5IaZTkLV0KncIt/DSTUdek5VD5f2R7dKDq4lKJOmSCKJrJR7wy8mf8N@PZhi/AQ)

#### How?

The method is the same as the one [used by Luis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237984/58563).

To compute the rank of a matrix, we look for the largest sub-matrix of size \$n\times n\$ whose determinant is not equal to \$0\$. This is most probably not the shortest way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 93 bytes

```javascript
f=B=>1/B[0][p=B.find(t=>t[0]),1]?!!p&&f(B.map(q=>q.map((v,i)=>v*p[0]-q[0]*p[i]).slice(1))):!p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDRboMwDHznK8JLlUwJI6Gl7aYwid9AeUAUqkwMwkD8PnMSxJi0bhJB9vnss@@9nMux@tRmYl1/q5dGwpfLjD/nRawKI/Oo0d0NTzKbACCUq7cwNIdDg/PoozR4kNngAjxTTWQ2PxngsQF@EGlForHVVY05IeQlNEvVd2Pf1lHb33GDiwCh4kIRO8PjFHGhqIUgZABfKUpSjwhAIGUneEcVKEJeg19mWU7iO1gC8x4zQSK2BMe1kd1gUxcu@6f5uG9O9708ftzrTo3tGZs8s3Kpu5eJP2StRRdvjaWLbcAK2JN/FvhqWeIW/j443S2RrN77CmRQPPlldhYuXw)

For testcase `[[8, 1, 2], [-7, -8, -9], [-1, 9, -5]], [12, 36, -4]` it input as `f([[8, -7, -1, 12], [1, -8, 9, 36], [2, -9, -5, -4]])`. Extra 47 bytes may be needed if we have to input as matrix B and vector V as two parameters.

This function simply reduce the array using Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 46 bytes

```
f(a,b)=#a==matrank(a)&&#matintersect(a,Mat(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU9BasMwEPzKkkCQYAW2lbg1xv1BXyB02ISkhLhBuL7k4q87s5bT3gqSmNmdmV0lGa7uK83zxQgfbbeVrvuWcZD7zYjd7bYg1/t4Hn7OpxGSTxnN0dpZUuofRsh9UBogANwo2dBJ@t5cmMRaphDCO1PJVLXk3pgcmGuAUWoAD3GCqKzY1@z2cYpgOiI47fo4aYZHQm4F2AqwdnmRmu285Ll/RXumGrRYNbqL7lRC42oA9JvftOoVpbn5AzD7VrGrdW/OVnVqza8XKYc2S@plCxTx3Yr1FOue/jXn72BctPMT)

Takes a matrix and a column vector as input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), <s>51</s> 41 bytes

```
Tr[1^#]&@@Solve[i=0;s@++i&/@#.#==#2]===i&
```

-10 (!) bytes due to @att

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDLCsIwELz7FQuFXky0SWy1SCCfIOitVCgiGvABWryUfnudTX2fhAQys7MzuzlW9X57rGq/qbqd7VaXQq2jMnZueT7ctoW3yfzqhkMfj100iqyNdGmt9XG3uPhT7XZF08wEKUG6FdTIqSAJLPOAQOcAactIaUEmA5y05eDdLVlhgsLAqC3powiDhEkUk0dKsEJLuH@pJ4IQq5JvMU/az6wglll4Qpq/EvSPPUf2u8LOsIo35Y1SngUuvQmz5nFhOCCiNBSyXg6h4RxQ@BIdiLCOeUa/Dyag7g4)

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVDLCsIwELz7FQuFXky0SWy1SCCfIOitVCgiGvABWryUfnudTX2fhAQys7MzuzlW9X57rGq/qbqd7VaXQq2jMnZueT7ctoW3yfzqhkMfj100iqyNdGmt9XG3uPhT7XZF08wEKUG6FdTIqSAJLPOAQOcAactIaUEmA5y05eDdLVlhgsLAqC3powiDhEkUk0dKsEJLuH@pJ4IQq5JvMU/az6wglll4Qpq/EvSPPUf2u8LOsIo35Y1SngUuvQmz5nFhOCCiNBSyXg6h4RxQ@BIdiLCOeUa/Dyag7g4)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 61 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 54 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
function(B,v,`+`=Matrix::rankMatrix)+B-nrow(B)|+rbind(B,v)-+B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDNCsIwDL77FD02LIW1dVMHXnb35gOok8EQOyjz5@C71yytOj0JTZuG7yeJD@06tBfXDF3vZI1X3GW79WY/@O5eVX7vTjGHrFbO9zdZwyPzh84dRzCorA6tPDNENnKJQqMwKNSCgn5qRUGl8SkALeIWUDRSE8aWVJwDzCYCjLeA@gW0pPgNIbWcbeJtAM1bNZqp/xlzFNSFzgHElLGIQ2giKO6SJph2TyXzYzIax/GJYDlnapF0yrQQm4IkiwQpuTPLWzJ88jQIbaKYmH4OQHgC)

Port of [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237984/55372).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 43 bytes

```
⊞θηＷ∧θ⌈Φ§θ⁰κ≔ＥΦθλＥκ⁻×μι×§§θ⁰ν§κ⌕§θ⁰ιθ⁼θ⟦Ｅη⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY49C8IwEIZ3f8WNF0jBby1OHRQcCh3cSoagxRym0Tat9t/HS6WLByE87/vex9Xo9vrUNoSi9wYbCUYcZh9DtgLM3C0quR6o7ms8ke2qFrPu7G7VEJ25kPAQXJB5T3eHuX5NMbatiM0vfPBHrvd4obryWEsgdn4wTfub6vhNErefiE/5i5AYS0LDFxctuQ6PTa@tj4Ey7jUxqIQ4hFCW5V7CQsJSsZnsJCTMSToSyynDRkVaLCWstoxrpULytl8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @tsh's JavaScript answer.

```
⊞θη
```

Append the vector to the basis.

```
Ｗ∧θ⌈Φ§θ⁰κ
```

Repeat until the basis becomes degenerate...

```
≔ＥΦθλＥκ⁻×μι×§§θ⁰ν§κ⌕§θ⁰ιθ
```

... perform Gaussian elimination on the basis, dropping the first row.

```
⁼θ⟦Ｅη⁰
```

Check whether the result is a zero vector.